# Microsoft Dynamics CRM - Pass Parameters from Web Service to IPlugins

Tags: web-services, plugins, microsoft-dynamics

We are building some plugins in Microsoft Dynamics CRM by inheriting from `IPlugin`. We have these configured so they fire whenever an `Account` is updated.

The problem is the plugins are calling our services, which causes our service to respond with an update. We are doing some pretty hacky things right now to prevent these cyclical updates from happening.

We were wondering if there was a way to pass a value to the `IOrganizationService` service (the web service) that a plugin can look at. Our other system could send a flag ("hey, don't bothing sending an update!") and the plugin could skip calling back.

Can we pass parameters from web service to the plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided the correct solution was to use the value found in `IPluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]`. In the case of an `Update`, this returns an `Entity` containing attributes for all the attributes that were updated.

We basically have a list of attribute names we cared about. We loop through names and see if any of them appear in the entity attribute list. If so, we send an update to our other system. The good news is, Dynamics CRM ignores updates where the values don't actually change, so trying to update a value to itself is no-op.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
    string[] fields = new string[] { "name", "statecode", "address1_line1" };
    bool hasUpdates = fields.Where(f => entity.Attributes.Contains(f)).Any();
    if (!hasUpdates)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good idea could be usage of custom flag-field. For example you add bit field and call it CallFromExternalSystem. So when you make an update from your external system through IOranizationService you just fill this flag with true field and in plugin you can check condition that this field is present in fields list so you have no need to call external system endpoint again.

Comment: We thought about having a GUID field that we'd set whenever we sent an update to the service. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for `SetState` and `Assign` requests.

Comment: In this case - you should define some user account (and in Plugin you can get using what account call was initiated). In case call was done that account - this means that call was done from external system.

Comment: and (if not already done) set the filtering attributes for each update step. if the external system and the plugin will not update the same fields then this should be sufficient. If they update the same fields you can look on the context depth to prevent infinite recursion (not nice i must admit). IMHO all other options are already given by @andrii-butenko (using flags/different calling users)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible by using a special-parameter called *tag*.

You can do the following with the IOrganizationService:

```
var createRequest = new CreateRequest();
createRequest.Target = yourEntity;
createRequest["tag"] = "Your Custom Value";

organizationService.Execute(createRequest);
```

Then you can access "tag" in the InputParameters of the plugin.